# Creating pivot table is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA script to create a Pivot Table, but unfortunately it isn't working.

The whole script is as follows:

```
Sub SeparateBrandNonBrand()
'
' Last Months Data Summary
' 
'
   Dim PT                     As Excel.PivotTable
   Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                              "2013-10-28!R1C1:R200000C20", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion1).CreatePivotTable( _
                                              TableDestination:="'Data-Summary'!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
                                              DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion1)
   With PT
      With .PivotFields("Sites")
         .Orientation = xlRowField
         .Position = 1
      End With
      With .PivotFields("campagin")
         .Orientation = xlColumnField
         .Position = 1
      End With
      .AddDataField .PivotFields("visits"), "Sum of visits", xlSum
   End With

End Sub
```

But specifically at run time the script complains that the following part of the code is invalid (invalid procedure call or argument).

```
Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                                  "2013-10-28!R1C1:R200000C20", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion1).CreatePivotTable( _
                                                  TableDestination:="'Data-Summary'!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
                                                  DefaultVersion:=xlPi

votTableVersion1)
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may result in this error

`Version:=xlPivotTableVersion1` & `DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion1`

Try recording a macro to capture the correct version, in my case, 14